# Using singleton class instance as class level variable is acceptable?

Tags: java, class, variables, singleton

I have a singleton class. `MsgLog`

Can I use this class like below? Is there anything wrong with this?

```
public class SomeBean {
   MsgLog log = MsgLog.getInstance(); // IS THIS FINE?

   // some code
   private void someMethod() {
        log.printIt(" test ");
   }
}
```

Comment: Where else is that `MsgLog` instance used? What does its `printIt` method do?

Comment: @milkplusvellocet just logger

Comment: that's not very helpful. Without knowing the internals of your class it's difficult to advise on how it should be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's fine. You should probably make it `private static final` though.

In general there are issues with singletons; it's better for a class to accept the things it depends on as constructor parameters than for the class to depend on singletons.

But lots of code treats logging specially, for better or worse.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. But I didn't get why it should be private? Could you please clarify?

Comment: Because nothing outside the class should care about how this class does its logging. (Always use the most restrictive access you can; relaxing restrictions is easier than tightening them.)

Comment: If another class extends this class, keeping it protected may be fine?

Comment: Yes, it can be. (Although I'd definitely make it final then, just to make it clear that no extendng class can change it.)

Comment: Yes. `final static` are standard. Thank you!

Comment: When this MsgLog class is serializable, this doesn't work. :(. I understand having a serialized MsgLog is preety bad.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is perfectly acceptable and most would argue that this is the proper way of using a Logger class. Here is another stack overflow answer that explains it a little better:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4085524/2016771