# Class diagram with 3 or more design patterns

Tags: design-patterns, uml

I got an assignment on my university to create a model of an simple app in UML. That model should use 3-4 different design patterns. Since i'm terrible in UML, could anyone please check if this thing i made makes any sense? If not how should i modify it? Any ideas how to include 1 more design pattern inside this little monster?

[image]

Comment: Opinion-based. Your model looks good _to me_, except for singleton (why restrict logger to single instance?).  

Also, design patterns are there to solve problems. It's no good to use design patterns 'for the sake of design patterns'.

Comment: I know that, but its not me who is making those assignments up :) For the logger as singleton - i red it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085463/why-we-should-consider-the-logger-class-as-a-singleton

Comment: You may include some complex message type and use builder pattern for its construction. The factory should then probably create MessageBuilder rather than Message.

Comment: Your decorator misses the association to `Message (decorated)`. In my opinion you should keep in mind how you would actually implement this. How would the encryption decorator actually work? It probably needs some more data exposed by `Message`. Maybe `display()` should just return something that the decorator can encrypt? The interface implementation arrows should have a closed head (like the specialization arrows). A possible addendum is a *Strategy* for the message's display method. You can implement different strategies for different mediums (text output, html output etc.).

Comment: Idiotic assignment, you never start an app with the purpose of implementing design patterns. You apply patterns if there is a need for them, and in many cases you won't be knowing you've applied one.

Answer (score 1):

Semantically it looks correct (in lack of more background information).

Even without adding more patterns, your diagram is too complex and hard to follow. On the other side, your design ideas should not be constrainet by your diagram size of screen resolution.

The solution is simple - divide to conquer. :) Break your diagram in several smaller ones, each one of them having a clear focus. That will not change your model meaning - each element can be shown on many diagrams.

I suggest the following diagrams:

- **a package diagram** showing only the packages and their dependencies - this is very important, architecture relevant diagram, a "bird view" on your system
- a **class diagram** for each package, showing its internal structure. It is also valid to add the external classes, which on which the package contents depend (or are used by them)

Give each diagram a meaningfull name and a short explanation.